# pgAdmin4 fails to launch on Linux (Arch)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, python

After installing pgAdmin4 with `sudo pacman -Sy pgadmin`, when I try running it, it gets stuck on the starting screen:

[image: Starting Screen of pgAdmin]

It doesn't even close visually (`xorg`), I need to do it with `killall pgAdmin4`. The error log I get is this, when launching from the terminal:

```
QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
Semaphore name: "pgadmin4-philippe-a59283b86ae8ae85d20fdf770d799dd7-sema"
Shared memory segment name: "pgadmin4-philippe-a59283b86ae8ae85d20fdf770d799dd7-shmem"
Python path:  "/usr/lib/python3.10:/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload:/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages"
Python Home:  "/usr/lib/python3.10"
Webapp path:  "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
^C"An error occurred initialising the pgAdmin 4 server:\n\nFailed to launch the application server, server thread exiting."
```

[image]

I've also tried to install it through `pip`, but it's the same thing. Right now, I'm using a containerized image of pgAdmin4.

Comment: BTW, removing Qt from tag & title since it is in no way involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read about this problem some times ago in [gentoo bugzilla](https://bugs.gentoo.org/774348)

As you can read, the culprit was identified as being [API breaking flask-security > 3.4.5](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#version-4-0-0)

So, for some time, the problem went worked around by forcing dependencies to :

- flask-security < 4
- flask < 2

When it became difficult to maintain those deprecated versions… gentoo devs incidentally removed pagAdmin4 from the repo.

I cannot tell regarding Arch repo. But, provided flask-security and flask still exist in those old versions AND you have made sure that no other package you installed depend on higher versions then… you could try downgrading.

Comment: Or maybe downgrade to pgAdmin3?